# ng-pattern (regex) to validate drive letters

Tags: angularjs, regex, regex-negation, angularjs-ng-pattern

I'm having little hard time with a regular expression. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Problem: I want display an error when user enters drive letters in the path.

for example: if user enters C:\ or D:\ or S:\ ....  the form should show an error.
If someone enters //remote server/example.txt it should allow them to proceed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/jyKfOdnctnhCkIeT4r2Z?p=preview

```
<form name='myform'>      
     <input type="text" name='ip' ng-model="usd" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]:*$/"
     ng-change="convert_to_btc()" placeholder="Enter path"/>
```

Comment: I think you need `ng-pattern="/^(?![a-zA-Z]:\\)/"`, check [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3UcFZNsjxPkVXkUJizu2?p=preview). If you need to disallow it not only at the start of the string: `ng-pattern="/^(?!.*\b[a-zA-Z]:\\)/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-pattern` requires a "positive" regex, some pattern that is defining what string is a correct one. So, when you define `^[a-zA-Z]:*$` that means you only allow strings that start with an ASCII letter, then have `:` zero or more times, up to the end of string.

You need a negative lookahead:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?![a-zA-Z]:\\)/"
              ^^^           ^
```

The `(?![a-zA-Z]:\\)` lookahead fails the match if there is an ASCII letter after the start of the string, followed with a `:` and then `\`.

See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3UcFZNsjxPkVXkUJizu2?p=preview).

If you need to disallow a letter + `:` + `\`  not only at the start of the strin use

```
ng-pattern="/^(?!.*\b[a-zA-Z]:\\)/"
                 ^^
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I need. Now I know how it works :)